# how to alert whatever response you want base on the ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image]I was working on making a facial recognition system. I used the API called Kairos.The response I got back is the data of the feature of a face or an error message from a nonface image. How can I change the response and display them on the screen, such as "success! It's a face" or "There's no face". I tried to if/else statement, but it seems that there's no response from it. How should I do it?

```html
<script>
$("#testDetect").click(function () {
    var file = $('#imageFile')[0].files[0]; 
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      var imageData = parseImageData(reader.result);
      var data = {};
      data.image = imageData;
      $.ajax({
     url      : "http://localhost/Karios/simple-detect/form-post.php",
     type     : "POST",
     data     :  data,
     dataType : 'text'
   }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        if (!response) { // Something unexpected happened. The message body is empty.

            alert('Hmm, unexpected response from Kairos');

        } else if (response['Errors'] && response['Errors'].size() > 0) { // If Errors is defined in the response, something went wrong.

            if (response['Errors'][0]['ErrCode'] == 5002) { // This appears to be the error when no faces are found.

                alert(response['Errors'][0]['Message']);

            } else {

                alert('Some other error occurred:\n' + response['Errors']['ErrorCode'] + ': ' + response['Errors']['Message']);

            }
            
        } else { // If there are no errors in the response, can we assume it detected a face? I guess so.

            alert('Face(s) detected');
            // The response has a ton of information about what it saw, including gender, age, ethnicity
            // and more.

        }
  
})
}
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Does your code work? Does the `alert` and `console.log` work as expected? Why not just put the response into an element on your page?

Comment: have you tried using `.fail()` in addition to `.done()`?

Comment: can share the output when the response is success and where is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response that you receive, you can write what you want to be displayed:

```
if(response === true){
  alert('success!');
}
else{
  alert('fail!');
}
```

EDIT

To redirect to another page, use: `window.location = http://mywebsite.com;`

To make a button unclickable, you will need to set the disabled attribute: `document.querySelector('button').setAttribute('disabled',true);`

EDIT

If this is your response: `{"Errors":[{"Message":"no faces found in the image","ErrCode":5002}]}` then you will have to parse it first because it will most likely be a string. Then in your conditional statement, check to see if it exists.

```js
var obj = '{"Errors":[{"Message":"no faces found in the image","ErrCode":5002}]}';

obj = JSON.parse(obj);

if(obj.Errors){
console.log("errors exist");
}
```

Comment: @JimmyLiao happy to help :)

Comment: @JimmyLiao make sure to accept an answer once SO allows you to.

Comment: If I want to redirect to another page if it successes and block/"gray" the button if it fails, how can I do that?

Comment: It seems that even there isn't a face, the response is still "success", why would that happen? Is it because the response is always true?

Comment: @JimmyLiao my answer was only an example. You have to create a conditional statement based on what the API is actually giving you. I'm sure the API will return an error so whatever that error is, use that as the conditional statement.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add it. Could you please write it out for me? thanks a lot!

Comment: The error message is "{"Errors":[{"Message":"no faces found in the image","ErrCode":5002}]}"    I tried to put it as the condition, but it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient. I tried again, and it didn't work :(   I searched about JSON.parse online, and your code does make sense, but both responses will still alert "success"... Do you know why it still happens? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `.done(function(response) {

     var obj = '{"Errors":[{"Message":"no faces found in the image","ErrCode":5002}]}';

    obj = JSON.parse(obj);

    if(obj.Errors){
    alert("errors exist");
    }
      else {
        alert("success")
      }
      })
    }
      }); `

Comment: change it to this: `var res = JSON.parse(response); if(res.Errors){` etc.

Comment: The Same result :( I updated my post, and I posted a picture of what I saw when I use `console.log` I think that might help you.

Comment: Check my code above. I edited a little bit. It works if there's a face, but if there isn't a face, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `.done()`, you can call `.fail()` which will run when the ajax was unsuccessful.

```js
$("#testDetect").click(function() {
  var data = {}
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/Karios/simple-detect/form-post.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'text'
  }).done(function(response) {
    alert(response)
  }).fail(function(error) {
    alert("Not a face")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testDetect">Test</button>
```

Comment: Your method works. But If I want to redirect to another page if there's a face, and gray/block the button if there isn't a face, how can I do that? I seem that every time I want to do something, both response will execute the line...

Comment: When you say `I seem that every time I want to do something, both response will execute the line...` do you mean that it shows two alerts? You can search stack overflow for help on how to redirect and disable a button if that is your desired next course of action.